# Amd athlon 6000+ kernel panic during installation

Tags: kernel

I am trying to install ubuntu 10.04 on my PC. I get flashing scrollock and capslock lights and error kernel panic
here screen shot http://alexandrneverov.livejournal.com/pics/catalog/443/47342

Installation of 11.04 (x86_64 and i386) - get the same. 12.04 can't start installation process. If install system on other PC and then pick this hard with installed system in this PC - it works maybe 5 min and then frezze or reboot.
What can i do to install ubuntu?? I have changed memory, video, atx, hard - no matter - it shuts down randomly, sometimes with this errors in image.
What can i do to install ubuntu??

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the kernel source that error message seems to indicate that the processor was having problems copying back Level 2 cache data back to memory.  The error is a machine check exception which is a low level hardware failure and nothing to do with a faulty operating system.

It either means you system memory is failing for some reason, or there is a bus issue or perhaps the CPU itself has issues.  It is hard to tell without direct access to the AMD handbooks and some deeper knowledge.  Since you have said you have already changed the memory and you still get the problem then it may be an issue with the CPU or the motherboard.

Comment: after a long time of experiments with ubuntu a have decided to boot debian 6.0.6 32-bit. It crashes when boot in normal mode, BUT! it boots sucсessfully in recovery mode. I don't want to breake my mind with trying to make it work with linux and get it back to seller.

Comment: I suspect it may boot in recovery mode because you are not really exercising the machine too deeply.

Comment: Of course, information about error on screen shot + deep knowledges about what is going on during system boot process could help me. But i can't see at this moment the decision. And Google too. May anybody tell me what service, or kernel module, or maybe something else i should change the way of it's work in order to enable normal  system boot?

Comment: I seriously think if you get a lot of MCEs then something is unhappy with the hardware somewhere. Honestly, I look at tens of thousands of bugs each year and whenever you get serious MCEs like this is it invariably H/W related.

Answer (score 0):

I, myself was having the same problems described in the posts listed above..  After A LOT of research and playing around,,, I determined that it was a problem with the DVD Disk I had burned the ISO file to. I re-burned to a fresh DVD and it resolved the problems.. Hope this may help others..

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It may be useful to others if you could describe how you determined that the DVD disk was faulty. Please edit your answer with additional information to make it more useful. Thanks.